# Beginner question: RASP PI 4 - Python - IOError

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi4, ioerror

Im trying to establish my own Raspy-Installation with a light-control.

I am trying to get a script-code working, to enable the light-control-service.

I am getting a really simple error message, but i cant fix it on my own:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    bus.write_byte_data(0x39, 0x00 | 0x80, 0x03)
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I just want to show you the complete code. Is anyone able to help me? :)

```
from os import system
system("sudo killall pigpiod")
system("sudo pigpiod")
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import pigpio
import smbus


bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
#Lichtsensor (Adresse 0x39) initialisieren
#Power On Mode
bus.write_byte_data(0x39, 0x00 | 0x80, 0x03)
bus.write_byte_data(0x39, 0x01 | 0x80, 0x02)

#kurze Pause
time.sleep(0.5)

#Lichtsensor auslesen
data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x39, 0x0c | 0x80, 2)
data1 = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x39, 0x0e | 0x80, 2)

#Lichtdaten aufbereiten
ch0 = data[1] * 256 + data[0]
ch1 = data1[1] * 256 + data1[0]

#Lichtdaten ausgeben
print "Volles Spektrum (Infrarot+sichtbar) : %d lux" %ch0
print "Infrarot-Wert: %d lux" %ch1
print "sichtbares Licht-Wert : %d lux" %(ch0 - ch1)

#GPIO ports setzen und zuweisen
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
red = 17
green = 27
blue = 22
PIR = 5

GPIO.setup(red, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(green, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(blue, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(PIR, GPIO.IN)
pi = pigpio.pi()

#Variablen definieren
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(red, 0)
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(green, 0)
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(blue, 0)
fade_in_delay = .1
fade_out_delay = .1
delay_time = 5
mycolor = blue
brightness = 200
min_light = 9
moment = 0

RUNNING = True

#Script starten
try:
    while RUNNING:
        data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x39, 0x0c | 0x80, 2)
        data1 = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x39, 0x0e | 0x80, 2)
        ch0 = data[1] * 256 + data[0]
        ch1 = data1[1] * 256 + data1[0]
        light = ch0 - ch1
        print "sichtbares Licht-Wert : %d lux" %(light)
        if pi.read(PIR):
            print "PIR = ON"
        else:
            print "PIR = OFF"
        if moment > 1:
            start = moment
        else:
            start = 0
        if (pi.read(PIR) & (light < min_light)):
            for x in range(start,brightness):
                pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(mycolor, x)
                time.sleep(fade_in_delay)
                moment = x
                while (pi.read(PIR) & (light < min_light)):
                    time.sleep(delay_time)
                if not (pi.read(PIR) & (moment > 0)):
                    for x in range(brightness, 0, -1):
                        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(mycolor, x)
                        time.sleep(fade_out_delay)
                moment = 0
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        RUNNING = False
```

I couldnt transform the usual tools to fix the problem i got by using google. Im also just a beginner in writing own python-scripts. Normally I´m looking for existing codes (like this) and get it done for my own use case.

Comment: Have you checked that I2C bus 1 has a device at address 0x39 ?

    i2cdetect -r 1